# must have, have to have, or should have: What should I use?

Tags: have-to-versus-must

> You must have the physical and mental strength to accomplish whatever you want in sport

You can see the sentence above, I want to say. I want to say some fact, and want to express some obligation, that it ***must-have*** for achieving something in sport, but as I see, construction ***must have*** used in different cases. According to [this source](https://www.businessenglish.com/grammar/modals-cant-have-must-have-might-have.html?lang=eng) we use it when we want to express believing that the action definitely happened. Can I use ***must have*** in my case, or it is used in the wrong way?

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing the use of ***have*** as a main verb with its use as an auxiliary - part of a modal form. Your sentence is correct. ***Must*** is used as a *modal* whereas ***have*** is the *main verb* expressing possession.

This is not the case with ***must have*** used "to express believing that the action definitely happened". If you look at the examples given at the link you provide, ***must have*** is the past modal form of *must*, so ***have*** is not the main verb:

> She *must have* ***left*** the house by now; it’s nearly 11 o'clock.

The main verb in this sentence is ***left***, not ***have***. Here "have" is only used to mark the fact that the action the speaker makes guesses or deductions about is a past action.

Comment: With reference to the question title; _must have_ and _have to have_ imply necessity, _should have_ sounds more like a recommendation.

Comment: @KateBunting Correct. I have not addressed this issue, as "must have the physical and mental strength..." was correct. But you are right to point it out.